# Base Class required libs inherited by all children

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to expose a required library in a base class to a child class. Primarily out of convenience. Ex: including a logger library accessible to all child classes, but not a global one.

I have this working by assigning the included logger in the base class constructor as such:
this.logger = logger;

Now the child class has available the base class required file.

this.logger = logger;

The expected result is accessible base class property representing a logger. This works. My ask here is if this approach has any performance drawbacks or if there are better approaches?

Comment: Nah, performance-wise it's fine, it just violates the single responsibility principle.

Comment: That is an excellent point.  So, I want to see if this changes the answer at all? The base class is actually for a node controller.  It establishes utility functions that can be used by child controllers for things such as error logging, and other workflow steps a controller would typically handle. 

This keeps the focus in the child class on domain specific controller functions such as for a user or another entity.

It works, and works well. Just leaves me with a feeling there is a better approach.  Thanks again for the feedback, very useful!!